# Is there a sequence following "ace" (as in "ace pilot")?

Tags: synonyms, terminology

If an expert pilot or covert operative or other specialized profession can be referred to as an "ace", is there a word that describes someone who is less experienced or lacks some of the expertise? Is it sequential? What pattern does it follow?

Comment: In military aviation Ace is a title of achievement. To be called an Ace you must have five confirmed kills in aerial battle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a pattern to this, but there are synonyms, antonyms and ways to phrase the opposite to varying degrees of status. For instance, if we take your example in a number of forms:

- Ace pilot
- Distinguished pilot
- Virtuoso pilot

Then we can construct some to refer to those lacking some skill but aspiring:

- Amateur pilot
- Rookie pilot
- Novice pilot

And further, construct some to refer to those that, despite any involvement and experience, don't have skills at all really:

- Incompetent pilot
- Inept pilot

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is.

> Ace: very good.

The term most likely comes from the Ace being the highest valued card in a deck of playing cards.

The playing card most likely got its name from the French word 'as' meaning  'a unit', since the ace is a representation of a single pip.

However, the lowest valued card is the 2 of clubs. Maybe you could refer to a lesser experienced person as a 'deuce'.

Comment: Using [deuce](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=deuce) to refer to a person might be slightly more insulting than intended, given this slang definition.

Comment: @Kit Haaha.. Yeah..